# What is the maximum number of topics an ActiveMQ broker is able to handle?

Tags: java, performance, jms, activemq-classic

I have the following generic problem: given N sources of information, with M possible types of info for each source, what is the most efficient way to handle the topics hierarchy in ActiveMQ?
Typically N can be 100s to 10000s, while M should be 10.

**Option 1**

Have a hierarchy like

- source1.*
- source2.*
- ...

and a smart consumer that (on the application side) just drops the types of info not required.

**Option 2**

Have a hierarchy like

- source1.type1
- source1.type2
- source1.type3
- ...
- source2.type1
- source2.type2
- source2.type3
- ...

with a dumb consumer that accepts every message.

=================================

Option1 probably allows more sources, but more work on the consumer side (and more traffic on the network), while Option2 should be more efficient on the network traffic (and hopefully performances) but it could be much heavier on the broker resource consumption.

What's the best option?

Thank you very much

cghersi

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with multiple sources publishing to the same topic. Generally it's a good idea to keep topics and queues down to manageable levels.

I would go for topic Type1, Type2, .., Type10

You can attach metadata to published messages with additional information using String properties. That way consumers can subscribe only to the data they really want using [JMS selector](http://activemq.apache.org/selectors.html) that might include things such as data source, info type, date, priority, or what not.

```
MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(topic, "source = 'EU-market'");
```

If there would be 10 times 1000 of topics, each client would have to open listeners to multiple topics to get all information. Typically, a listener requires threads which requires a good portion of stack allocation. Better to let the clients decide by a selector.

This does not answer the question of what's the maximum limit of topics. Topics and queues adds overhead to the broker. They are registered as JMX MBeans and are shown in the web console gui. They might also allocate internal threads and memory resources. To figure out if a number of topics works or not - better test it with the setup intended to run it. Your milage may vary